# How do I use SFSafariViewController with a dark theme like this user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios9, sfsafariviewcontroller

I saw in a screenshot to a StackOverflow question that a user presented a darkened SafariViewController: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36099965/998117

How is this accomplished? I can't seem to get it to take effect using `UIAppearance`.

Comment: Dark one is private mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the Safari App , if you enable private browsing mode then it will change in your app also