# How to achieve Incognito Mode in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

In the APP i'm currently working on, I need to provide user with a way to open HTML file. I'm using `SFSafariViewController` for that purpose. However, it is also required that user need to be able to view HTML file in *incognito* mode.

I did some research and find out that user can click on 'safari' icon in `SFSafariViewController` to open a certain HTML file in Safari APP. Then user can use *private* browsing mode of Safari as he/she always does.

However, I'm trying to figure out any way for user to use *incognito* or *private* browsing mode in `SFSafariViewController`?

If not, is there any alternative to `SFSafariViewController` which can achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36551946/468724

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Thanks man, now I got it. Incognito mode is already there and user just need to turn in on in Safari APP. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have any control over `SFSafariViewController` in terms of customization. [Read Further](http://developer.outbrain.com/ios-best-practices-for-opening-a-web-page-within-an-app/) for more information regarding the different ways of opening a web-page within an app.

I would suggest you to use `UIWebView` if you are supporting iOS versions below 8.0 and `WKWebView` for versions overs 8.0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! What confused me is exactly that we don't have any control over SFSafariViewController. I was wondering how could we achieve incognito mode in SFSafariViewController without having control over it. And the comment above just solved my question. Incognito mode is already in SFSafariViewController. Thank you again for help.

Comment: Actually you cannot force any option onto SFSafariViewController as it is independent safari instance and you have no control over it from within your app. It would be highly appreciated if you could accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: But how to do it in wkwebview/uiwebview ?